# Find two solutions for a PDE in a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ point $ xu_x-2x^2u_y=u,u(t,0)=t^5 $

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The problem is:

$$
xu_x-2x^2u_y=u,u(t,0)=t^5
$$

I used the method of characteristics to find a solution and got:
$$
u(x,y)=x(y+x^2)^2
$$
Since $J=0$ at $(0,0)$ there should exist 2 solutions in any neighbourhood of this point, but I can't find another one. I would like to know how should I approach it and what would be another solution?

Comment: I am sorry if there was a misunderstanding, but there should be 2 different solutions in the neighborhood of this point. Also the solution you suggest does not satisfy the initial condition.

Comment: Are you treating $t$ as $x$?